# Knockout custom validation issue

Tags: validation, knockout.js

Say I have a model with following properties:

```
function ViewModel() {
     this.SetupTime = ko.observable();
     this.CloseTime = ko.observable();
     this.MinHrs = ko.observable();
}
```

I need to add a validation rule so that MinHrs > (SetupTime + CloseTime). Whenever one of the three fields is changed this validation should fire. I know I have to write a custom validation for this, for example:

```
    ko.validation.rules['ValidWorkRange'] = {
    validator: function (val, setuptime, closetime, minhrs) {
        return minhrs > (setuptime+closetime);
    },
    message: '(Shift End - Shift Start) >= Shortest Work Segment'
};
```

I'm not sure what I have done there is correct, also not sure how to call this validation within the observable.

Can someone please help me out?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right, you should create a [custom validation](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation#custom-validation-rules) to achieve your goal. And you have no need to call validation function, it will be automatically called whenever its associated dependency (observables) will change.

[**Wroking Fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/udojob/28/edit)

**Note** : Please apply the other necessary validation like number etc. Because if you enter text in any input field in the fiddle code than result may be an error.

Here is the custom validation code :

```
var ValidWorkRange = function(val, param)
{
  if(val && param){
  var minHrs = parseInt(val, 10);
  var setupTime = parseInt(param[0](), 10);
  var closeTime = parseInt(param[1](), 10);
  return minHrs > (setupTime+closeTime);
  }
};
```

And like this you can apply it on your observable :

```
function ViewModel() {
     var self = this;

     self.SetupTime = ko.observable();
     self.CloseTime = ko.observable();
     self.MinHrs = ko.observable().extend
     ({
       validation: { 
         validator: ValidWorkRange, 
         message: 'Not valid.', 
         params: [self.SetupTime, self.CloseTime] 
       }
     });
}
```

Comment: Hi, it'w working nicely thanks. You have been helping me a lot lately :) Anyway I'm still struggling with properly displaying error messages using a custom template. I've explained it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802620/knockout-validation-issue-with-custom-message-tempalates appreciate if you can help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know so much about ko validation but probably it can be usefull for you

https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation

Comment: I did follow the documentation and found a lot of help there, but unfortunately not a help for this particular scenario.